# how to get a count of <input> tags in an HTML page with python for weblist dropdown

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find list count in below Xpath (drop down list).

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='macro-param-div']/div/ul/li/input")).
```

I tried this with select method but seems it will not work with html tags having input method. How to get the count?

Comment: driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('input'). Note the "s" in elements

Comment: Can you share which website you're scraping and the code that you tried?

Comment: print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//[@class='macro-param-div']/div/ul/li/input"))) should print the number of inputs out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### find_element_by_xpath()

[`find_element_by_xpath(xpath)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) finds an element by xpath.

To create a *list* instead of `find_element_by_xpath(xpath)` you need to use **`find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)`** and use `len()` as follows:

```
print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='macro-param-div']/div/ul/li/input"))))
```